# How do I check if a number lies between two members of a mathematical progression? e.g. A.P., G.P. or any other progression

Tags: javascript, math

I want to  assign a level to a number as below:

If a number lies between 3 and 3+3^2  `Level` should be 2.

If a number lies between 3+3^2 and 3+3^2+3^3  `Level` should be 3.

If a number lies between 3+3^2+3^3 and 3+3^2+3^3+3^4  `Level` should be 4.
.... 
And so on...

I am trying this..

```
var level = (next_slot>3 && next_slot < 3+3**2)?1:(
                      (next_slot>3+3**2 && next_slot < 3+3**2+3+3**3)?2:(
                        next_slot>3+3**2+3**3 && next_slot < 3+3**2+3+3**3)?3:(
                          4
                      ))
```

Which seems complex and also there is no limit to it.

Is there any better way to solve this in javascript?

Comment: Just a minor feedback, its a bad practice to use nested ternary operators

Comment: Your example doesn't match your explanation: there your limits aren't 3^3, they're 3^1+3^2+3^3. Which is correct? The first you could solve with log-to-base-3, subject to rounding errors, but the latter you're probably best using a loop and counting up until you find an upper bound for next_slot.

Answer (score 3):

Use logarithm, Luke:

```
level = Math.ceil(Math.log(x) / Math.log(3))
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to make a for loop with some max constant and then exit when you find that you're in between the values

```js
const checkLevel = function(number) {
  if (number <= 0) {
    return 0 // failsafe since 3^0 is 1
  }

  const max = 10
 
  for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    let low = Math.pow(3,i)
    let high = Math.pow(3,(i+1))        
    console.log('our low is ' + low + ' and our high is ' + high)
    console.log('lets check if ' + number + ' is between')

    if (number >= low && number < high) {
      console.log('it matches')
     return i+1
    } else {
      console.log('no match, lets continue')
    }
  }
}

const level = checkLevel(4)

console.log('level',level)
```

What we are doing here is:

1. Start from 0
2. Create our low value 3^0
3. Create our high value 3^1
4. Check if our number is between
5. Return it if that's the case
6. Otherwise continue

Next it will check 3^1 and 3^2 and so forth

Answer (score 0):

From your latest edit it looks like this is no longer possible to do with logarithms, so you will need to count up instead:

```
function findLevel(input) {
    let level = 1;
    let limit = 3;
    let increment = 3*3;

    while (input > limit) {
        ++level;
        limit += increment;
        increment *= 3;
    }

    return level;
}
```

You didn't specify the behaviour for the limits themselves, i.e. whether 3 belongs to level 1 (the 0-3 range) or 2 (the 3-12 range). This assumes that it belongs to the lower level, i.e. 3 is on level 1 not 2. Change `input > limit` to `input >= limit` if that's incorrect, i.e. 3 is on level 2.

```
// Print the inclusive integer ranges for each level
let lastLevelStart = 0;
let lastLevel = findLevel(lastLevelStart);
for (let i = 1; i <= 10000; ++i) {
    let level = findLevel(i);
    if (level != lastLevel) {
        console.log(`level ${lastLevel}: ${lastLevelStart} to ${i-1} inclusive`);
        lastLevel = level;
        lastLevelStart = i;
    }
}
```

> level 1: 0 to 3 inclusive
>   level 2: 4 to 12 inclusive
>   level 3: 13 to 39 inclusive
>   level 4: 40 to 120 inclusive
>   level 5: 121 to 363 inclusive
>   level 6: 364 to 1092 inclusive
>   level 7: 1093 to 3279 inclusive
>   level 8: 3280 to 9840 inclusive

This obviously takes the output level number of loops to compute, and when reused will end up repeatedly computing the same limit values over and over again (albeit using integer maths only, so relatively cheaply). So if you call this a very large number of times or need to deal with more than a small number of levels then you may want to compute the upper bounds for the first 1000 levels (say) into an array and then just scan that to find the level, or even binary search that array to find the answer in a more constant time (checking first that the input is <= the top precomputed value, and falling back to this method if not).